# Is there an function for writing all Elements and Characteristics from Revit in an .csv file?

Tags: python, revit-api, autodesk, pyrevit

I use Revit(PyRevit) and want to wirte all used Elements with their characteristics in an .csv file.

This is one example:

```
Get Parameter Value by Name 
Get value of one of element's parameters.

TESTED REVIT API: 2016,2017

Author: Francisco Possetto | github.com/franpossetto

Shared on www.revitapidocs.com
For more information visit http://github.com/gtalarico/revitapidocs
License: http://github.com/gtalarico/revitapidocs/blob/master/LICENSE.md
"""

#Imports.
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import Element

doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
uidoc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument

def get_parameter_value_by_name(element, parameterName):
    return element.LookupParameter(parameterName).AsValueString()

#Select elements from revit.
selection = [doc.GetElement(x) for x in uidoc.Selection.GetElementIds()]

#Example with Walls.
for wall in selection:
    print get_parameter_value_by_name(wall, "Base Constraint")
```

But there I only get "Base Constraint" is it possible to get all Elements/Categories into that file?

Thanks a lot. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use rpw [Collector](https://revitpythonwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/db/collector.html) to get all FamilySymbol elements. If you only want all instances in your project. Just use '*FamilyInstance*' to get them.

```
from rpw import db

collector = db.Collector(of_class='FamilySymbol')
elements = collector.get_elements()

for e in elements:
    print(e.name)
```